# Can I disable autocreate S3 Bucket in Zappa Init?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, serverless-architecture, zappa

I want to get started with zappa framework, but when I'm running init zappa I got this notification:
[image]

How to disable autocreate s3 bucket?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Zappa first uploads your .zip file to a bucket and from there does the deployment.

From the [official repo](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/#initial-deployments):

> Zappa will automatically package up your application, [...] **upload the archive to S3**, create and manage the necessary Amazon IAM policies and roles, register it as a new Lambda function, create a new API Gateway resource, create WSGI-compatible routes for it, link it to the new Lambda function, and finally **delete the archive from your S3 bucket**. Handy!

So your option is to dig into Zappa and circumvent this on your own or perhaps try [Chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice) that does the upload directly.

Answer (score 0):

@mislav is correct that Zappa does need an S3 bucket.  But one only gets auto-created if you don't specify one.  Simply provide a valid bucket name at the prompt, and Zappa will use that bucket instead of creating one for you.